# Plotting three variables on an XY plane, involves distance formula.

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

I have 3 dynamic constants with values of 0 to 1.
Lets label them A,B and C.
I want to be able to plot them on a 2 dimensional cartesian plane.
so given all three constants I will be able to find the XY coordinates.
Imagine three lines that connects directly in the middle from the corners of an equilateral triangle , and the constant number is the percent retracted that sting is.
given (a,b,c) find (x,y)

I know the value of a few for example,

0,0,1=0,0

0,1,0=(0.5,0.86602540378443864676372317075294) I rounded to 1.

0,1,1=(0.25,0.43301270189221932338186158537647) I rounded to .5

1,0,0=1,0

1,0,1=(0.5,0)

1,1,0=(0.75,0.43301270189221932338186158537647) I rounded to .5

Refer to the attached picture for a more clear example.
I'd like a formula that I can replace A,B, and C with my known values to get the X and Y coordinates.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates of your three points are $A=(1,0)$, $B=\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$, $C=(0,0)$. Given three weights $a$, $b$, $c$, the following formula gives the same answers as you give above:
$$\frac{aA + bB + cC}{a+b+c}.$$
Whether that is the formula you want is not clear, at least to me, without more examples.

Comment: Note that one can equivalently require that $a+b+c=1$. This is sensible, because the formula amounts to choosing a linear combination of the three points that remains within the triangle (i.e. their convex hull). @Mike

Comment: How do I reverse this? I'm sure it will have multiple answers, so lets limit this from 0 to 1 for A B and C. ___ X=(a+.5b)/(a+b+c) ___&___ Y=(b*((3^.5)/2))/(a+b+c) ___ so I'd like a A=, B=, and C.

Comment: Rogerl is right. Semiclassical is wrong. Now I'd like to reverse the 2 formulas.